# delay in receiving data from Android to Arduino

Tags: android, arduino, usb, arduino-due

I'm connecting my android device to arduino via USB and I receive data immediately from arduino by using bulkTransfer, but when I'm going to send acknowledge signal back to arduino using the same command, it receives that some seconds later.

My arduino model is DUE, and the arduino side code is:

```
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(49, OUTPUT);
}
void loop() {
  String a;

  int sensorValue[64];
  for (int i = 0; i <= 63; i++)
  {
    sensorValue[i] = analogRead(A0) / 4;
    a = a + char(sensorValue[i]);
  }
  char b;
  while (1) {
    Serial.print(a);
    Serial.flush();
    delay(2);
    b = Serial.read();
    if (b == '1')
    {
      break;
    }
  }
  digitalWrite(49, HIGH);
  delay(2000);
  digitalWrite(49, LOW);
}
```

My android side code is:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            synchronized (this) {
                if (usbDeviceConnection != null) {

                    Thread myThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            try {
                                int chunkCounter = 0;
                                String strTemp = null;
                                while (chunkCounter < 1) {

                                    byte[] message = new byte[64];

                                    final int result = usbDeviceConnection.bulkTransfer(endpointIN, message, 64, 10);

                                    if (result == 64) {
                                        for (int intTemp = 0; intTemp < 64; intTemp++) {
                                            strTemp += String.valueOf((char) message[intTemp]);

                                        }

                                        byte[] ack = new byte[1];
                                        ack[0] = 1; //1 means I've got this chunk
                                        synchronized(this) {
                                            int resultAck = 0;
                                            while (resultAck <= 0) {
                                                resultAck = usbDeviceConnection.bulkTransfer(endpointOUT, ack, 1, 10);
                                            }
                                        }
                                        chunkCounter++;
                                        if (chunkCounter == 1) {
                                            final String strTempFinal = strTemp;
                                            tempflag = true;
                                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void run() {
                                                    txtGetData.setText(strTempFinal);
                                                }
                                            });
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            } catch (final Exception e){
                                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    });
                  myThread.start();


                }
```

Any help would be appreciated.
thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `bulkTransfer` ? I asked that before!

Comment: `send acknowledge signal back to arduino using the same command` ? Which command is the same on Android and Arduino?

Comment: `it receives that some seconds later.`. How many seconds by `delay(2);`.?

Comment: @greenapps bulkTransfer is synchronous way to send data via usb in Android using Endpoints IN and Endpoints OUT.

Comment: @greenapps using the bulkTransfer I receive data  and send ack back in android. the direction of transferring data is determined by the direction of endpoints.

Comment: @greenapps not 2ms, 3 to 7 seconds later.

Comment: And what does it have to do with your Arduino code? You only try to send a string of 64 characters. Or how many? Please give an example of the contents of string a.

Comment: Then how do you change endpoints if you want to send data back?

Comment: @greenapps a sample data is ababababababccccccabababababac.. 64 data of a & b & c or 64 other characters

Comment: It's time you show your Android code.

Comment: @greenapps endpoints IN and OUT are found in android side code. They are working, but the problem is the delay in receiving data.

Comment: Can you tell how it looks at Android side? How soon do you see txtGetData.setText(strTempFinal);?

Comment: And `while (resultAck <= 0)`. Does it loop several times? How long does the send transfer take?

Comment: @greenapps transfer is done in a matter of second, but the data is received in arduino some seconds later

Comment: Can you apply a flush() on Android side? And what is this parameter `10` ?

Comment: @greenapps 10 is timeout, I do not know any flush on android side

Comment: 10 minutes or so?